# Is it possible to define priviledge method outside of the constructor?

Tags: javascript

Well I have this constructor with one secret and one method:

```
function Keeper(get) {
    var secretPower = 'wisdom';

    this.get = get ? get : function () { 
        return 'Its secret power is: ' + secretPower; 
    }
    // now this is privileged method only in case that there are no arguments?
}
```

Now I will make two instances, one has privileged method...

```
var yourKeeper = new Keeper();
yourKeeper.get();       // "Its secret power is: wisdom"
```

... but the another one is different. It can touch context around it, but not privates of the constructor ...

```
var myKeeper = new Keeper(function() { 
        return 'Its secret power is: ' + secretPower; 
    });
myKeeper.get();         // ReferenceError: secretPower is not defined
```

... also this doesn't work as I want:

```
myKeeper.get = function() { 
    return 'Its secret power is: ' + secretPower; 
}
myKeeper.get();         // ReferenceError: secretPower is not defined
```

Of course it won't work, because `secretPower` is global variable in these cases, so:

```
var secretPower = 'none';
myKeeper.get();         // "Its secret power is: none"
```

So **is it possible to define priviledge method outside of the constructor?** How?

**Can it be done with eval?** (I know... it is evil... Im just interested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to define privileged methods outside of the constructor. Here is how to do it:

```
var Keeper = (function (key) {
    function Keeper(get) {
        var private = {
            secretPower: "wisdom"
        };

        this.getPrivate = function (k) {
            if (k === key) return private;
        };

        this.get = get || defaultGet;
    }

    function defaultGet() {
        var private = this.getPrivate(key);
        return "The secret power is: " + private.secretPower;
    }

    return Keeper;
}({}));
```

Here is how it works:

1. We create a namespace by creating an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).
2. We create a object called `key`. This object is private to the namespace we just created. Hence only privileged functions and the constructor can access it.
3. Inside the constructor we create an object called `private` which holds the private state of each instance.
4. We also create a privileged method called `getPrivate` which takes an argument `k` and only returns the private object if `k` is the `key` we created in step 2. Hence only privileged functions can access the private object.
5. Privileged functions which want to access the private state of the object must call `getPrivate(key)` to get the private state object.

**Note:** This method is only useful if you have more than one privileged function which needs to access the private state of the object. In addition the call the `getPrivate` introduces a (very) small performance overhead to privileged functions.

---

BTW if you want to write clean object-oriented code in JavaScript then take a look at the [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) library. The above code will looks like this using `augment`:

```
var Keeper = Object.augment(function (key) {
    this.constructor = function (get) {
        var private = {
            secretPower: "wisdom"
        };

        this.getPrivate = function (k) {
            if (k === key) return private;
        };

        this.get = get || defaultGet;
    };

    function defaultGet() {
        var private = this.getPrivate(key);
        return "The secret power is: " + private.secretPower;
    }
}, {});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Anyway, I have a question:

Create new instance of the Keeper and pass function as an argument. Try to return secretPower with that function. It is possible only if you create instance inside of namespace. 
I understand that defaultGet is priviledge function that is made outside of the constructor. Anyway, it is still binded to namespace... which almoast implicate that it is inside of the constructor.

Comment: @Windkiller No. There's only one instance of `defaultGet` which is shared amongst all instances of `Keeper`.

Answer (score 2):

The very idea behind the scoping in javascript is that this shouldn't be possible, what I would advice is adding a function `getPrivate` within the scope of the constructor and use that to access 'private' variables.

```
function Keeper(get) {
    var semiPrivates = {
        secretPower:'Wisdom'
    }

    this.getPrivate = function (variable){
        return semiPrivates[variable];
    }

    this.get = get ? get : function () { 
        return 'Its secret power is: ' + semiPrivates["secretPower"]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: As `myKeeper.getPrivate('secretPower')` could be called from outside, there would be no difference to calling `myKeeper['secretPower']`.

Comment: Yeah, but the question already wants to somehow expose 'private' variables, so this construction will at least allow control over which 'private' variables are accessible and won't clutter the object.

Comment: @marsze There will be difference. You can't change value of secretPower with getPrivate() method.

Comment: Thanks for the fix@Windkiller, wasn't paying attention. And that's only true if the variable in question is not an object. Because an object will be passed 'by reference' in javascript rather then a copy like strings of other base variable types. (I think I have the terminology wrong here, but can't be bothered to find the right terms :P )

Answer (score 1):

I would never actually do it this way but here is a solution with `eval`:

```
function test(){
    var private = 'hello';

    this.say = function(){

    }

    this.setSay = function(func){
        eval('this.say = ' + func.toString());
    }
}

var x = new test();
x.setSay(function(){
    console.log(private + ' world');
});
x.say();
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/claustrofob/AwMd3/

And here is an example related to your `Keeper` object:

```
function Keeper(get) {
    var secretPower = 'wisdom';
    var getFunc = function () { 
        return 'Its secret power is: ' + secretPower; 
    };

    var evalFunc = function(variable, val){
        eval(variable + ' = ' + val.toString());
    };

    this.__defineSetter__("get", function(val){
        evalFunc('getFunc', val);
    });

    this.__defineGetter__("get", function(val){
        return getFunc;
    });

    if (get !== undefined){
        evalFunc('getFunc', get);   
    }
}
```

here we define setter and getter for your `get` method so you can init your objects this way:

```
var x = new Keeper(function () { 
    return 'Its secret power is: ' + secretPower; 
});
```

and this way:

```
var x = new Keeper();
x.get = function () { 
    return 'Its secret power is: ' + secretPower; 
};
```

live example http://jsfiddle.net/claustrofob/yu6VJ/